# GA Debug Shows Ecommerce Transaction Sending, but Data is Not Showing Up

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, e-commerce

Using a framework that gives limited source control (Blackbaud Internet Solutions), I am trying to implement Google Analytics ecommerce tracking into my site.

Because I am using a custom donation form, [link]this code(https://www.blackbaud.com/files/support/guides/bbis/tkConfigureE-Commerce.html) from BB's documentation doesn't work, and most developer's guides from Google assume more source control than BBIS allows.

This is in the "Site tracking" section under the Administration > Sites & settings > [Site name] > Settings tab (assume that's in the head for those unfamiliar with BBIS).

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXX-XX"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXX-XX');
  gtag('require', 'ecommerce');
</script>
```

This code appears at the bottom of the donation confirmation page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function returnDonationObject() {
      // First get the donation
      var gift = document.getElementById("givingSummary");
      var tds = gift.getElementsByTagName("td");
      var totalDonation = 0;

      for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
        if(tds[i].innerText.indexOf("$") > -1) {
          var transformedNum = parseFloat(tds[i].innerText.slice(1, tds[i].innerText.length));
          totalDonation += transformedNum;
        }
      }
      totalDonation = totalDonation.toFixed(2);

      // Then get the GUID from the url
      var guid = window.location["href"].split("?t=")[1];

      // create and return the object
      var donationObject = {
        "transactionId" : guid,
        "transactionTotal" : totalDonation
      }
      return donationObject;
  }

  var donationObject = returnDonationObject();
  gtag('event', 'purchase', donationObject);
</script>
```

returnDonationObject returns the transactionId and transactionTotal as expected, and using the GA Debug extension, it appears the final gtag('event', 'purchase') function fires successfully:

```
Running command: ga("gtag_UA_XXX_XX.send", "event", {forceSSL: true, &gtm: "2ou6k2", hitCallback: [function], eventCategory: "ecommerce", eventAction: "purchase"})
Sent beacon:
v=1&_v=j77d&a=220349989&t=event&_s=3&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fsite-name.com%2Ffoundation%2Fdonate%2Fgive-online%3Ft%3Db2d87d89-e000-4457-8e43-xxxxxx&dr=https%3A%2F%2Fpayments.blackbaud.com%2FPages%2FSecurePayment.aspx%3Ft%3Db2d87d89-e000-4457-8e43-xxxxxxx&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=Foundation%20Donation%20Form&sd=24-bit&sr=1920x1080&vp=1313x937&je=0&ec=ecommerce&ea=purchase&_u=SCEAAUAL~&jid=&gjid=&cid=760857713.1560526567&tid=UA-XXX-XX&_gid=216294229.1562588238&gtm=2ou6k2&pa=purchase&z=1491483290

VM49 analytics_debug.js:16 <unknown>        (&gtm)  2ou6k2
VM49 analytics_debug.js:16 _j1              (&jid)  
VM49 analytics_debug.js:16 _j2              (&gjid) 
VM49 analytics_debug.js:16 adSenseId        (&a)    220349989
VM49 analytics_debug.js:16 apiVersion       (&v)    1
VM49 analytics_debug.js:16 clientId         (&cid)  760857713.1560526567
VM49 analytics_debug.js:16 ec:action        (&pa)   purchase
VM49 analytics_debug.js:16 encoding         (&de)   UTF-8
VM49 analytics_debug.js:16 eventAction      (&ea)   purchase
VM49 analytics_debug.js:16 eventCategory    (&ec)   ecommerce
VM49 analytics_debug.js:16 hitType          (&t)    event
VM49 analytics_debug.js:16 javaEnabled      (&je)   0
VM49 analytics_debug.js:16 language         (&ul)   en-us
VM49 analytics_debug.js:16 location         (&dl)   https://site-name.com/foundation/donate/give-online?t=b2d87d89-e000-4457-8e43-xxxxxxxx
VM49 analytics_debug.js:16 referrer         (&dr)   https://payments.blackbaud.com/Pages/SecurePayment.aspx?t=b2d87d89-e000-4457-8e43-xxxxxxx
VM49 analytics_debug.js:16 screenColors     (&sd)   24-bit
VM49 analytics_debug.js:16 screenResolution (&sr)   1920x1080
VM49 analytics_debug.js:16 title            (&dt)   Foundation Donation Form
VM49 analytics_debug.js:16 trackingId       (&tid)  UA-XXX-XX
VM49 analytics_debug.js:16 viewportSize     (&vp)   1313x937
VM135:29 {transactionId: "b2d87d89-e000-4457-8e43-xxxxxxxxx", transactionTotal: "78.02"}
```

However, ecommerce data is still not flowing to Google Analytics (I have waited well more than 48 hours since implementing this code). Any chance somebody can identify what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you send an event-hit instead of an transaction-hit. The Data you send at the moment should show up as a Event-Hit in GA. Make sure to send an transaction Hit with all the required fields.

Comment: Do you want to send a standard ecommerce transaction hit, or an enhanced ecommerce transaction, which is an event hit enriched with ecommerce data?

Comment: A standard transaction hit would be just fine. If I could get just the transaction values flowing that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone struggling with this in the future, the problem was actually pretty simple. I was just using the key names from an older implementation of Google Analytics in `donationObject`. Changing `donationObject` to this got data flowing:

```
var donationObject = {
   "transaction_id" : guid,
   "value" : totalDonation
}
```